# document.ready() inside a function after and Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an application that is using ajax calls for loading the content. Those ajax calls are retrieving just the HTML. JavaScript is in another file.

After doing the AJAX-call I will call to a function that should start executing the JavaScript as soon as possible.

Here I leave a small function that will retrieve some code from an ajax call:

```
function loadPage(page) {
    $(".container").html("");
    if(page == "page1") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/page1.php",
            success: function(html){
                $(".container").html(html);
                loadPage1Script();
            } 
        });
    }else if(page == "page2"){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/page2.php",
            success: function(html){
                $(".container").html(html);
                loadPage2Script();
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

After that, they will execute `loadPage1Script()` or `loadPage2Script()`.

```
function loadPage1Script(){
    //Start the carousel plugin, for example
}
```

A new code has been added to the HTML structure. Should I call to `$(document).ready();` in the `loadPage1Script()` before executing the code to to attach all event handlers? Is there any differences if I do not do that? Will the script start faster if I add the `$(document).ready();` ?

```
function loadPage1Script(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Start the carousel plugin, for example
    });
}
```

Taken from jQuery site(http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> "*In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the `loadpage` function after you have aleady called

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    ...
});
```

Then it shouldn't matter. Also, since the `$.fn.html` function isn't asynchronous, you will have no problem in running your `loadPageScript` functions straight away

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `$(document).ready()` inside of those functions, because by the point they're run the DOM elements they need will already be present (you just inserted them into the page prior to calling the function).

You should, however, call the original `loadPage` function inside of `$(document).ready()` to ensure that the `.container` element(s) exist.